# Restarting at line 0 in a "For line" statement in python

Tags: python, file, for-loop, line

I have a code that look like this:

```
while True:
with open('file', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        #Doing something with a different var a each iteration of the while True.
```

And I'd would like to know if there's a way to restart a "for line" loop at line 0 in order to open the file just once before the beginning of the while true instead of opening it a everytime. Thank you

Comment: I think you can do whatever it is you want to do with a single scan of the file, IO is more expensive than memory.

Comment: The file is quite large (+- 140 000 line for 10 mb) do you think it's better to load all the file in memory ?

Comment: It depends on the actual problem. 10MBs is nothing generally. If you can summarize the file with a scan it can be even smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually have to restart the loop. You just need to go back to the beginning of the file.

```
import os

f = open('file', 'r')  # don't use 'file' as a variable name
while True:
    f.seek(0)
    for line in f:
        # do stuff

f.close()
```